# In my Django API, I am generating a PDF file. I want to send a request to a PHP file which handles upload to upload that file. Here is what I wrote:

Tags: php, api, file-upload, request

```
url = 'url.to.the.php.file.which.handles.upload'
files = {
   file: ('file_name', open('file/path', 'rb'))
}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I also tried the following

```
url = 'url.to.the.php.file.which.handles.upload'
files = {
   name: 'file_name',
   file: open('file/path', 'rb')
}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

And also tried by changing 'files' to 'data' as follows

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

In the PHP file, I have the following code (if it helps)

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tempPath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_no=substr($filename,0,10);
```

I am either getting an 'Internal server error' or no error - but the file is not being uploaded.

Comment: Have you tried `files = {'file': open('myfirstreact.png' ,'rb')}`

Comment: Yes, that too doesn’t work sadly